# Re add node to ocfs2 cluster

Tags: linux, iscsi

i'm trying to re add node with new clear OS to ocfs2 cluster  using old node name and ip. But facing a error

> mount.ocfs2: Cluster stack is invalid while trying to join the group.

I also cannot remove the node from the cluster, what should I do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everything was resolved after executing the commands like

```
register-cluster 
start-heartbeat
```